# How to get a list of Interface members

Tags: c#

Is there a way to get a list of interface members? I know about System.Reflection.MemberInfo, but it includes everything in an object, not just a certain interface.

Here is the program, I'm not sure how to get you the interface as I didn't write it, but it is part of the Ascom Standard ([http://ascom-standards.org](http://ascom-standards.org/)).

```
public static void Test1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("mark1"); // this shows up...
    var type = typeof(Ascom.Interface.ITelescope);
    var members = type.GetMembers();
    Console.WriteLine(members.Count); // gives 0
    foreach (var member in members)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(member.Name); //nothing from here
    }
    Console.WriteLine("mark4"); // ...as well as this
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you have two `Type` objects, one for a `class` (or `struct`) and one for `interface` and you want to get the methods that implement the interface in the class. Is that right? Why do you want them?

Comment: I just want the interface list. I'm trying to dynamically implement the interface at runtime, fyi.

Comment: Oops, interface *member* list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a COM interface, then you should disable "Embed Interop Types", otherwise it will only insert used members in the assembly. I guess you don't use any methods/properties from that interface in the assembly, that's why they never get inserted, so you can list them with reflection. (Thx OWO)

Answer (score 8):

From MSDN:

```
typeof(IList).GetMembers()
```

> Gets the members (properties, methods, fields, events, and so on) of the current Type.

Comment: If you want to filter to just the properties from this, you can use Linq: `typeof(IList).GetMembers().OfType<PropertyInfo>()`.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to ask for the members *for the interface type*:

```
var type = typeof(IConvertible);
var members = type.GetMembers();

foreach (var member in members)
{
    Console.WriteLine(member.Name); // ToInt32 etc
}
```

Comment: @Arlene Beiler: For which interface? It works fine for me... I tried it with the code I posted.

Comment: Would it have anything to do with the interface being marked public rather than its members? When I browse it in the object browser, it says the interface is public, but none of the members are marked as public.

Comment: @ArlenBeiler: Interface members are implicitly public. If you can give us a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, that would make life easier...

Comment: if I ask for `members.length` it gives me 0

Comment: By the way, I tried it with `IConvertible` and it worked fine.

Comment: I see what you mean about interfaces being public. `IConvertible` shows up exactly the same in the object browser.

Answer (score 2):

```
var t = typeof(IMyInterface);
foreach( var m in t.GetMethods() ){
    Debug.WriteLine(m.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of members of some interface, you can just do that: list members of that interface, as others pointed out:

```
var members = interfaceType.GetMembers();
```

But if you want to know what members of certain type implement that interface, you can use [`GetInterfaceMap()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfacemap.aspx) and examine [the `TargetMethods` field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.interfacemapping.targetmethods.aspx):

```
var members = type.GetInterfaceMap(interfaceType).TargetMethods;
```