# Can Visual Studio help me to find out whether a member of a class is declared in an interface that the class implements

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio for C#, is it possible to find out whether a member of a class is declared in an interface that the class implements or is defined in the class or its ancestry class? If declared in an interface, which interface? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe add some example to better explain what you mean?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm not sure that edit was a good one. It sounded to me like Tim wanted to know how to figure it out *using Visual Studio*, not in code. I'll let them speak up though.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan now that you mention it, yes, it does sound more like that. I reverted my edit

Comment: @Mike: Yes, from Visual Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a list of Interface members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641267/how-to-get-a-list-of-interface-members)

Comment: You can find code for this ^, but if you're asking for a tool in VS, no.

Comment: Maybe search with Object browser can help.

Comment: If you use Resharper - it shows this information right away (on the left of the method definition, you can also click to navigate to interface). If you don't - consider start using it.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find Resharper, and how can I install it? @Evk

Comment: Just google "Resharper" but unfortunately it is not free. But it improves your development workflow so much that I think every serious .NET developer which uses Visual Studio just have no choice.